# How do you use the expression 'under the weight (of)'?

Tags: phrase-usage

Did I use it correctly?

> The suspect finally came clean with the interrogator **under the weight of** presented evidence.

If not or if it doesn't sound natural, what would you use instead of the bold text?

Comment: The only change I would make is "under the weight of **the** presented evidence", because we're not talking about evidence as a general idea, but the *specific* evidence that was presented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grammatical structure is ok, but you've created something of a mixed metaphor.

We usually use the phrase "under the weight of" in a figurative sense (ie. when not referring to literal, physical weight) as part of an extended metaphor about weight.

Consider this literal example:

> The bridge gave way under the weight upon it.

This describes the physical effect of a weight upon something.

Likewise, the usual figurative use would be more like:

> He finally caved in under the weight of evidence heaped upon him, and confessed.

The 'weight of evidence' is a commonly used expression in law, but as part of a statement with cause and effect it makes more sense to continue the metaphor. "Caved in" is just one expression which literally means to collapse, but figuratively means to 'give in'.